# I'm having a complex issue with my app using Flutter

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, service, sharedpreferences

I'm having an issue with my app written with Flutter, specifically related to `SharedPreferences` configuration. The issue is seen when running the app in release mode, where I am greeted by a white screen or sometimes a splash page with no ability to navigate or interact. The app works fine in debug mode though.
I added some Kotlin code for sending and setting local notifications, after which the issue came into existence.

What's even more confusing is that the debug mode doesn't show any significant errors, making it difficult to pinpoint the source of the issue.
I can share more code if needed.

```dart
import 'package:al_muezzin/bindings/initialbindings.dart';
import 'package:al_muezzin/core/constant/color.dart';
import 'package:al_muezzin/core/localization/translation.dart';
import 'package:al_muezzin/core/service/services.dart';
import 'package:al_muezzin/route.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:timeago/timeago.dart' as timeago;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await initialServices();
  timeago.setLocaleMessages('ar', timeago.ArMessages());
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

final MethodChannel _channel = MethodChannel('com.example.al_muezzin/AlarmManagement');

Future<void> setNextAlarm() async {
  try {
    await _channel.invokeMethod('setNextAlarm');
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Failed to set alarm: ${e.message}');
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'AL-JAZEERA',
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          backgroundColor: AppColor.secondColor
        ),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xffF2F2F2),
      ),
      locale: Locale('ar'),
      translations: MyTranslation(),
      initialBinding: InitialBindings(),
      getPages: getPages,
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
import 'package:al_muezzin/core/function/print.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class MyServices extends GetxService {
  late SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

  Future<MyServices> init() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return this;
  }
}

initialServices() async {
  await Get.putAsync(() => MyServices().init());
}
```

When I uninitialize the services, the app works, but with an experimental interface, because my whole app depends on this service

Comment: Have you tried putting the `await SharedPreferences.getInstance()` simply in the `main` method and see what happens? Just to simplify the code as much as possible to see if anything else is causing the issue

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'd like to point out that there are way too many issues with the code as of now. Why are you instantiating `MyServices` everytime inside `initialServices` method? Why are you creating a method specifically for providing an instance of the `MyServices` class? A `factory` constructor should do that.  You're calling the `initialServices` method in your `main` method, but I don't see any declaration of such a global function. Please provide relevant code snippets.